# How to create inline form in row column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to learn bootstrap grid and want to create a row with two columns: one wide and one not so wide.  In the left column I want to put an inline form and in the right narrower column I will put another form with a button. I copied Bootstrap example for 2 columns in one row and then I copied the Bootstrap inline form code and pasted it into one of the columns but it is not inline when I run the code. This is the code I have so far:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="MyContainer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <form class="form-inline">
        <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputName2">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">

        <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroupUsername2">Username</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroupUsername2" placeholder="Username">
        </div>

        <div class="form-check mb-2 mr-sm-2">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineFormCheck">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineFormCheck">
              Remember me
            </label>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      One of two columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Instead of the form controls being inline they are stacked one on top of the other.

[image: Screenshot]

Can someone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried simply putting your `<form>` as `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`?

Comment: @Wolfeur.  Yes but it makes no difference.

Comment: You are using classes which are no longer supported in Bootstrap 5 (`.form-inline`, `.sr-only`…).

Answer (score 0):

You are using classes from older versions of Bootstrap, yet you use Bootstrap 5.1. I made some changes:
Firstly, it’s `.visually-hidden`, not `.sr-only` anymore. Secondly, `.form-inline` is no longer supported, so I changed the class to `row` and added `.col-3` classes to the form’s children. I also changed the two columns’ classes as you said you want one to be wider than the other. I don’t know what resources you use for Bootstrap, but I recommend relying on the [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="MyContainer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <form class="m-2 row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-3 mb-2 mr-sm-2">
          <label class="visually-hidden" for="inlineFormInputName2">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
        </div>

        <div class="col-3 mb-2 mr-sm-2">
          <label class="visually-hidden" for="inlineFormInputGroupUsername2">Username</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroupUsername2" placeholder="Username">
        </div>

        <div class="col-3 form-check mb-2 mr-sm-2">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineFormCheck">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineFormCheck">
            Remember me
          </label>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="col-3 btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      One of two columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work although I know it should because it works in the code snippet.  I updated Bootstrap and also added the CDN references and there is something still preventing it from working.  Basically no change.  I have tried to edit my post to share the link and script references from my shared layout page but It wouldn't let me edit so I'm basically stuck.  I am using bootswatch but when I removed the reference to that the form was still stacking.